# PhpSpreadSheet Charts TYPE_BARCHART_3D Custom colors

Tags: charts, phpspreadsheet

I ask for help in order to be able to customize the PhpSpreadSheet charts, preferably the bar type when exporting to excel so that it comes out in the cylinder shape and can define the colors of each bar independently

Here is my code

```
// Custom colors for dataSeries (gray, blue, red, orange...........)
$colors = [
     '00a3f5', '00a3f5', '00a3f5', '00a3f5', '00a3f5', '00a3f5', '00a3f5', '00a3f5', '00a3f5', '00a3f5', '00a3f5',
];
 
 $dataSeriesLabels1 = [
        new DataSeriesValues(DataSeriesValues::DATASERIES_TYPE_STRING, 'Worksheet!$B$1', null, 1), // 2010
    ];
  $xAxisTickValues1 = [
        new DataSeriesValues(DataSeriesValues::DATASERIES_TYPE_STRING, 'Worksheet!$A$2:$A12', null, 11), // PI to ANI
    ];
 $dataSeriesValues1 = [
        new DataSeriesValues(DataSeriesValues::DATASERIES_TYPE_NUMBER, 'Worksheet!$B$2', null, 11, [], null, $colors),
        new DataSeriesValues(DataSeriesValues::DATASERIES_TYPE_NUMBER, 'Worksheet!$B$3:$B$12', null, 11, [], null, $colors),
    ];


  $series1 = new DataSeries(
    DataSeries::TYPE_BARCHART_3D, // plotType
    null, // plotGrouping (Pie charts don't have any grouping)
    range(0, count($dataSeriesValues1) - 1), // plotOrder
    $dataSeriesLabels1, // plotLabel
    $xAxisTickValues1, // plotCategory
    $dataSeriesValues1          // plotValues
);
$layout1 = new Layout();
$layout1->setShowVal(true);
$layout1->setShowPercent(true);


$legend1 = new Legend(Legend::POSITION_RIGHT, null, false);

$title1 = new Title('My Bar');
$chart1 = new Chart(
    'chart1', // name
    $title1, // title
    $legend1, // legend
    $plotArea1, 
    true, 
    DataSeries::EMPTY_AS_GAP, 
    null, 
    null  
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much for your help, I was able to solve the problem by creating a kind of categories for each bar that wanted to add a color and create an additional table for the graph to search for the colors

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);

require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Chart\Chart;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Chart\DataSeries;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Chart\DataSeriesValues;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Chart\Layout;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Chart\Legend;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Chart\PlotArea;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Chart\Title;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Chart\Axis;

include 'conexao.php';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM global";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
$x=$row["indice_global"]-0.369;
$ty = ($x*100)/$row["indice_global"];
$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
$worksheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()
            ->setCellValue('A1',"Area")
            ->setCellValue('B1',"Nível de Implementação");
$media = array();
$nome_da_media = array();
$linha = 2;
$recomendacao = array("2.1","3.1","3.2","3.3","5.1","5.2","5.3","5.5","7.1","8","12","12.5","12.6","12.7","13.3","14.3","15.1","18","20.3","22.1","22.6","23.1","24","25","28.1","29.1","29.2","30.1","30.2","30.3","31.1","32","33","34","35","36","37","42");
for($i = 0; $i<count($recomendacao); $i++){
    $comando = "SELECT AVG(media_escala) as media FROM registo INNER JOIN progresso ON progresso.referencia=registo.referencia AND registo.codico_de_area = ".$recomendacao[$i];
    $comando2 = "SELECT registo.descricao_de_area FROM registo INNER JOIN progresso ON progresso.referencia=registo.referencia AND registo.codico_de_area = ".$recomendacao[$i];
    $result = $conn->query($comando);$row=$result->fetch_assoc();
    $result2 = $conn->query($comando2);$row2=$result2->fetch_assoc();
    if($row["media"] !=null && $row2["descricao_de_area"] !=null){
        $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()
                        ->setCellValue('B'.$linha.'', number_format($row["media"],0))
                        ->setCellValue('A'.$linha.'', $row2["descricao_de_area"]);
                       
        $linha++;
    }
}


$comando2 = "SELECT grau_global FROM global";
$result = $conn->query($comando2);$row=$result->fetch_assoc();
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()
            ->setCellValue('A'.$linha.'',"Media")
            ->setCellValue('B'.$linha.'', number_format($row["grau_global"],0));
                    

            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('K1')
            ->getFont()->getColor()->setARGB(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Color::COLOR_RED);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('L1')
            ->getFont()->getColor()->setARGB(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Color::COLOR_BLUE);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('M1')
            ->getFont()->getColor()->setARGB(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Color::COLOR_YELLOW);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('N1')
            ->getFont()->getColor()->setARGB(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Color::COLOR_GREEN);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()
            ->setCellValue('K1', 'ANI')
            ->setCellValue('L1', 'EPI')
            ->setCellValue('M1', 'PI')
            ->setCellValue('N1', 'TI');
$media = array();
$nome_da_media = array();
$linha = 2;
$recomendacao = array("2.1","3.1","3.2","3.3","5.1","5.2","5.3","5.5","7.1","8","12","12.5","12.6","12.7","13.3","14.3","15.1","18","20.3","22.1","22.6","23.1","24","25","28.1","29.1","29.2","30.1","30.2","30.3","31.1","32","33","34","35","36","37","42");
for($i = 0; $i<count($recomendacao); $i++){
    $comando = "SELECT AVG(media_escala) as media FROM registo INNER JOIN progresso ON progresso.referencia=registo.referencia AND registo.codico_de_area = ".$recomendacao[$i];
    $comando2 = "SELECT registo.descricao_de_area FROM registo INNER JOIN progresso ON progresso.referencia=registo.referencia AND registo.codico_de_area = ".$recomendacao[$i];
    $result = $conn->query($comando);$row=$result->fetch_assoc();
    $result2 = $conn->query($comando2);$row2=$result2->fetch_assoc();
    if($row["media"] !=null && $row2["descricao_de_area"] !=null){
        if($row["media"]>99){
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()
            ->setCellValue('N'.$linha.'', number_format($row["media"],0));
        }else if($row["media"]>50){
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()
            ->setCellValue('M'.$linha.'', number_format($row["media"],0));
        }else if($row["media"]>0){
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()
            ->setCellValue('L'.$linha.'', number_format($row["media"],0));
        }
        else if($row["media"]==0){
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()
            ->setCellValue('K'.$linha.'', number_format($row["media"],0));
        }
        $linha++;
    }
}
$comando2 = "SELECT grau_global FROM global";
$result = $conn->query($comando2);$row=$result->fetch_assoc();
if($row["grau_global"]>99){
    $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()
    ->setCellValue('N'.$linha.'', number_format($row["grau_global"],0));
}else if($row["grau_global"]>50){
    $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()
    ->setCellValue('M'.$linha.'', number_format($row["grau_global"],0));
}else if($row["grau_global"]>0){
    $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()
    ->setCellValue('L'.$linha.'', number_format($row["grau_global"],0));
}
else if($row["grau_global"]==0){
    $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()
    ->setCellValue('K'.$linha.'', number_format($row["grau_global"],0));
}


           
// $cor=
// Set the Labels for each data series we want to plot
//     Datatype
//     Cell reference for data
//     Format Code
//     Number of datapoints in series
//     Data values
//     Data Marker
$dataSeriesLabels = [
    new DataSeriesValues(DataSeriesValues::DATASERIES_TYPE_STRING, 'Worksheet!$K$1', null, 1, [], null, 'f20f0f'),
    new DataSeriesValues(DataSeriesValues::DATASERIES_TYPE_STRING, 'Worksheet!$L$1', null, 1, [], null, '09b4e3'),
    new DataSeriesValues(DataSeriesValues::DATASERIES_TYPE_STRING, 'Worksheet!$M$1', null, 1, [], null, 'fff203'),
    new DataSeriesValues(DataSeriesValues::DATASERIES_TYPE_STRING, 'Worksheet!$N$1', null, 1, [], null, '0ff247'), // 2010
    // new DataSeriesValues(DataSeriesValues::DATASERIES_TYPE_STRING, 'Worksheet!$B$1', null, 1, [], null, 'ff085a'), // 2011
    // new DataSeriesValues(DataSeriesValues::DATASERIES_TYPE_STRING, 'Worksheet!$D$1', null, 1), // 2012
];
// // Set the X-Axis Labels
// //     Datatype
// //     Cell reference for data
// //     Format Code
// //     Number of datapoints in series
// //     Data values
// //     Data Marker
$xAxisTickValues = [
    new DataSeriesValues(DataSeriesValues::DATASERIES_TYPE_STRING, 'Worksheet!$A$2:$A$42', null, 39),
    new DataSeriesValues(DataSeriesValues::DATASERIES_TYPE_STRING, 'Worksheet!$A$2:$A$42', null, 39),
    new DataSeriesValues(DataSeriesValues::DATASERIES_TYPE_STRING, 'Worksheet!$A$2:$A$42', null, 39),
    new DataSeriesValues(DataSeriesValues::DATASERIES_TYPE_STRING, 'Worksheet!$A$2:$A$42', null, 39),
     // Q1 to Q4
];
// // Set the Data values for each data series we want to plot
// //     Datatype
// //     Cell reference for data
// //     Format Code
// //     Number of datapoints in series
// //     Data values
// //     Data Marker
$dataSeriesValues = [
    new DataSeriesValues(DataSeriesValues::DATASERIES_TYPE_NUMBER, 'Worksheet!$K$2:$K$42', null, 39),
    new DataSeriesValues(DataSeriesValues::DATASERIES_TYPE_NUMBER, 'Worksheet!$L$2:$L$42', null, 39),
    new DataSeriesValues(DataSeriesValues::DATASERIES_TYPE_NUMBER, 'Worksheet!$M$2:$M$42', null, 39),
    new DataSeriesValues(DataSeriesValues::DATASERIES_TYPE_NUMBER, 'Worksheet!$N$2:$N$42', null, 39),
    
];
// $dataSeriesLabels->getFillColor()->setFillColor('5507f0');


    $yaxis = new Axis();
    $xaxis = new Axis();
    $yaxis->setAxisOptionsProperties('low', null, null, null, null, null, 0, 100, null, null);
    $yaxis->setLineParameters('FFFFFF',100,Axis::EXCEL_COLOR_TYPE_ARGB);
    $xaxis->setAxisOptionsProperties('low', null, null, null, null, null, 0, 0, null, null);

// // Build the dataseries
$series = new DataSeries(
    DataSeries::TYPE_BARCHART, // plotType
    DataSeries::GROUPING_STANDARD, // plotGrouping
    range(0, count($dataSeriesValues) - 1), // plotOrder
    $dataSeriesLabels, // plotLabel
    $xAxisTickValues, // plotCategory
    $dataSeriesValues        // plotValues
);
// // Set additional dataseries parameters
// //     Make it a vertical column rather than a horizontal bar graph
$series->setPlotDirection(DataSeries::DIRECTION_COL);

// // Set the series in the plot area
$plotArea = new PlotArea(null, [$series]);
// // Set the chart legend
$legend = new Legend(Legend::POSITION_RIGHT, null, false);

$title = new Title('Nível De Implementação Por Area');
$yAxisLabel = new Title('');

// // Create the chart
$chart = new Chart(
    'chart1', // name
    $title, // title
    $legend, // legend
    $plotArea, // plotArea
    true, // plotVisibleOnly
    DataSeries::EMPTY_AS_GAP, // displayBlanksAs
    null, // xAxisLabel
    $yAxisLabel,  // yAxisLabel
    $yaxis,
    $xaxis
);


// // Set the position where the chart should appear in the worksheet
$chart->setTopLeftPosition('D2');
$chart->setBottomRightPosition('Z25');

// // Add the chart to the worksheet
$worksheet->addChart($chart);

header('Content-type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Graficico_Indice.xlsx"');
header("Content-Description: PHP Generated Data");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Pragma: no-cache");



$writer = IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Xlsx');
$writer->setIncludeCharts(true);
$writer->save('php://output');
exit;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not all chart kinds are implented. Maybe this is one of the not supported ones.